# Define a term for a website user who does not have cookies activated

Tags: internet

I'm looking for a term that describes a user of a website that has not enabled the cookies of that website.

My initial though was *new user*, but an existing user could delete cookies if they wished, so *new user* doesn't work in that case.

Any ideas? I conducted a quick google search but drew a blank using the search term *define website user "not enabled cookies"*

Comment: perhaps just "cookie-blocked users".  but is it really relevant to this site?

Comment: I think he's called "a web site user who does not have cookies activated".  There's not a nice, neat 7-letter word for every concept under the sun.

Comment: A _cookie monster_.

Comment: Or I suppose you could say it's a user who has tossed his cookies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An *incognito user* sounds quite nice, knowing that browsers also use that very same adjective to denote users who wish not to have cookies saved on their computer.

Comment: +1 Looks good. Can you provide a reference for it?

Comment: Well I'm an English teacher and I checked the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary. The same explanation can be found here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incognito

Comment: [Google uses this as a special word for their private browsing mode in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en),  which does not only turn off just cookies but browsing history and all other traces the internet browser might leave on the H.D.D., such as cache and browsing history, to protect users from snooping. I am unsure whether its good that they approve of the word for this or bad that what you want to convey might be conflated for a broader functionality on Chrome browsers but I figured its worth mention.

Comment: As Tone points out, this is a no-go since it's already a "special term".

Comment: @JoeBlow - On the other hand, I don't think we can allow Google to dictate the meaning of *every* word they use in a technical sense. Surely others are allowed to have a say too. In general, if you intend to use a technical term in technical writing, you start by *defining* it. That way your readers know what you mean.

Comment: Hi Chasly.  Look, it it two steps from saying you want to use "iPhone" in your app to describe a smartphone.  Google is (by far) the biggest computer concern on Earth, Chrome is their browser, and "incognito mode" is perhaps the most common term from that browser. There are certain terms you can't use because they are already used specifically in very commonly used apps or OS. This is an example of that. Google is dictating nothing.  You say "every word they use in a technical sense" - which is utterly irrelevant here. We're talking one of the (let's say, 20 or so)...

Comment: ...terms used by Google in consumer products which are now universally understood (certainly by programmers) as having some specific meaning.  (You could say, no programmer or developer would ever even suggest this, as it's so obviously "already used".)

Comment: I'm not really happy with _incognito_ and can't see any reference to web users on Michael's definition page. There are many reasons why people might block cookies: it's not just a matter of being "unknown".

Answer (score 1):

A **cookie objector** or a **cookie recusant**

- objector - a person who dissents from some established policy
- recusant -  someone who refuses to conform to established standards of conduct